# Open Tok plugin conflicts with firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opentok

I'm using opentok plugin for making video sessions in my ROR app. unfortunately it is not working in firefox-firefox browser. if the peers are using firefox, then it is not working. I'm new to this.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Post more details and code

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb will do

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you firefox version is up to date and that all your users have the latest version of firefox. WebRTC is not supported in older Firefox versions. Once you have the latest firefox version, test this code for group video chat in multiple tabs/browsers/computer (you can get sessionId/token credentials from your dashboard account page):

...

```
<body>
  <script src='//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    var apiKey = "YOUR KEY";
    var sessionId = "YOUR SESSION ID";
    var token = "YOUR TOKEN";
    var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
    session.connect( token, function(err){
      if(!err){ session.publish(); }
    });
    session.on("streamCreated", function(event){
      session.subscribe( event.stream );
    }); 
  </script>
```

...